# Limit Recursive Foreign Key Depth in Django Model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django model with a nullable ForeignKey to 'self'. I'm interested in introducing a hard limit (say, 10) on the recursion depth. Where would be the proper place to check this and what sort of exception should I throw there?

Pseudo-example of what I mean:

```
def limit_recursion_depth(self):
    depth = 0
    model = self
    while model.parent is not None:
        depth += 1
        model = model.parent
    if depth > 10:
        pass # Complain here and stop processing
    else:
        pass # Return the model, save, whatever is normal
```

I am more interested in a solution like overriding the Model's save() method than any kind of validation which will only work for the admin. (For example, I'd like to be able to validate Model.objects.create().)

## Update

Even though this question was largely academic and related to a project I'm no longer pursuing, I wanted to update this in case anyone found this through Google. The following is from the [django-mptt documentation](http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/tutorial.html#the-problem):

> To get all those page titles you might do something like this:
>
> ```
> titles = []
> while page:
>     titles.append(page.title)
>     page = page.parent
> ```
>
> **That’s one database query for each page**...

Django-mptt is much more efficient even for small projects and I probably should have been using it even in this case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as explained very well in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1625760/2588818), there really *isn't* a good way to do this in Django. For example, the method above will simply crash the admin with a 500 error every time an end user hits the save button on a change form -- hardly helpful. The only proper way to do this is to [define `clean_{fieldname}` and throw a ValidationError](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/validation/). It doesn't validate, for example, a `model.save()` from the `manage.py shell`, but neither will overriding that validate, for instance, `queryset.update()`.

Therefore, the solution I went with now looks like this:

```
def clean_parent(self):
    depth = 0
    model = self.instance
    while model.parent is not None:
        depth += 1
        model = model.parent
    if depth > 10:
        raise ValidationError('Recursion Depth Exceeded')
```

Note this belongs in the admin form for the model.

Comment: What about situation, when parent will be defined for current root?)) This example does not check depth for descendants.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your complaint. Are you talking about checking depth in the other direction? If so, this could be easily modified to suit your purposes (and anyway that's not what the question was about).

Comment: I'm just try to explain - if there are need to limit nodes depth, we have to consider depth all of descendants. Just assume. 
A - root (depth=0)
B - another root (depth=0)
C - the Node in B  (C.parent is B) (depth=1)
The limit of depth in that Model 1 for example. 
For example we open B page edit and change parent from None to A. Current validation checks B depth and it will 1 and fine, but after rebuild tree the C will has depth is 2 and it rather than depth limit.

Comment: True -- this is why I suggested in my update that anyone doing this seriously consider using django-mptt. Checking descendants would be extremely expensive using a method like the one in this answer and not at all worth it performance-wise.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this?

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if Foo.objects.filter(foo=self.foo).count() > 10:
        raise Exception("not more than 10")
    else:
        super(Foo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Update:**

For `self` referential fields with `django-mptt` you could do something like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if Foo.objects.filter(foo=self.foo).get_descendant_count() > 10:
        raise Exception("not more than 10")
    else:
        super(Foo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This is definitely worth an upvote at least as soon as I get the rep to bestow one. I like the idea because it's simple, clear, and doesn't have any obvious problems (to me). If an answer like "Actually there is a way to do this normally in Django" doesn't come up soon I will definitely accept this. Thanks!

Comment: Now that I'm at home and have had time to study this, I do see a small problem. Your if condition actually checks if the parent of say, A, has greater than 10 children. I want to walk up A's ancestry to make sure A can't have a great-great-great-great-(to recursion depth) grandfather. Does that make more sense? Otherwise, this answers my question -- where to check (model.save()), and what to throw (generic or custom Exception). Also, what is `assert Exception()`. Shouldn't that say `raise`?

Comment: Yes I missed the 'self' part. If you're gonna be doing a lot of walking up the tree you should really check out [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/). And you are also right about that is should say `raise`.

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while since I've picked up this project, but I have to un-accept your answer. Django's admin only catches certain exceptions, so this method causes all the forms to crash with a 500 error if the recursion depth is triggered!

Comment: So override the save method on the form you want this functionality for. And yes, use ValidationError.

Answer (score 0):

Version without cycle:

```
    def clean_parent(self):
        parent = self.cleaned_data['parent']
        if parent and parent.level >= 10:
            raise ValidationError('Recursion Depth Exceeded')
        return parent
```

Note: levels starts from 0.

Comment: how does parent knows his level