# Django- limit_choice_to null

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am looking for the correct syntax for something like the following:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    parentCategory = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, limit_choices_to={'parentCategory__parentCategory':null})
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

The important like is:`parentCategory = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, limit_choices_to={'parentCategory__parentCategory':null})`

What's the correct syntax for: `limit_choices_to={'parentCategory__parentCategory':null}`

Comment: I'm not sure if they have a syntax for that, but you probably want to be using [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) for something like this. Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094426/limit-recursive-foreign-key-depth-in-django-model) from when I tried to do something similar. The answer there may help you.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I'll have a look. I too feared that it would be impossible.