# Django Does Not Throw Validation Exception When Email Field Is Not Valid

Tags: django

This is my model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(db_index=True, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=160, blank=True)
```

This code is not throwing a ValidationError even though email is invalid:

```
user = User(email='invalid e-mail address', 'password'='password_hash')
user.save()
```

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `.full_clean()` method to validate the attributes appropriately. Otherwise, the record will directly stored in DB.

```
>>> u=User(email="something", username='x', password="p")
>>> u.full_clean()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 824, in full_clean
    raise ValidationError(errors)
ValidationError: {'email': [u'Enter a valid e-mail address.']}
```

From documentation of [`full_clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean)

> Note that full_clean() will not be called automatically when you call
>   your model’s save() method. You’ll need to call it manually when you
>   want to run one-step model validation for your own manually created
>   models.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have to either use a ModelForm, or override your save method and call the `full_clean()` method before saving the User.

Source : [Django model fields validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624782/django-model-fields-validation)